# Drupal 7: Combining multiple content type in single view

Tags: view, drupal-7

I have a content type called Author which is referred in another two content types called Novel and Book via Node Reference Module.So we can add author entity to both Book and Novel content types.
Both Novel and Book contain another field called Release Date.
Now I want to show a block which will display the name of book and name of novel in chronological order based upon the release date when user come to that corresponding Author Page.

Ex. Suppose A is an author who is author of BookA(Release Yr-2006), NovelB(Release Yr-2004),BookC(Release Year-2009). When user come to Author A page then he will be shown a block which will show the Books/Albums in chronological order like this:-
NovelB--BookA--BookC

Please suggest as how to achieve in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah..I am able to solve this problem by adding custom code. I have used hook_views_query_alter method and then added join relationship and where clause as per requirement. Please refer to following article for more clarity..
http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/filtersearch-multiple-fields

Thanks for posting the reply and keeping my hope alive.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the following field `title` (I assume the book name is the node title)

For the sorting you can use the sort option in views, it is pretty self-explaining. Choose the name of your release date field.

For the connection between author and books you will have to use a contextual filter (advanced). 
Add the `author-reference-field` from your book/novel (the field you use to refer to the author). Then choose to use a default value (2nd option) and choose `content id from url`. Now your block will find all nodes that refer to the page with the current page-id. Since we chose to display the title fields, you should see a list.

**Note that live preview does not work here, so you will have to go to the actual page to see the result.**

**UPDATE**:
This works when you have re-used the same field for both content types. If you have uses more then one field you will have to use an OR operator to make the contextual filter work. Thanks to [d34dman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445354/d34dman) the following [page](http://mario.net.au/content/drupal-views-contextual-filter-or-operator) was given to do just that. 
Although for new implementations I would recommend using the same field (eg. reference_to_author) for all references from all content types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Whatever you suggested will work fine when i need to display one content from book/Novel.But here I want to display both content then I need to add both connection in contextual filter. This will not bring any result as multiple contextual filter will support AND and all the data are filtered this time.Also there is no way to add OR logic to Contextual filter. Please help me as this obstacle is ruining my day.

Comment: It depends, I always re-use my fields. Using a field with the same properties for several content types. This keeps everything simpeler. So when you use the same field for both content-types. (Add existing field) the results will be from both types

Comment: Incase giving an 'OR' saves the day, please look at [this](http://mario.net.au/content/drupal-views-contextual-filter-or-operator) article on how to change AND to OR for contextual filters. And please update the answer accordingly giving reference.

Comment: Sorry for being late. Was busy in other work.                 @D34dman- I went through the article provided by you.When there are two parameters added in contextual filters then query doesn't run.So the task of converting "AND to "OR" inside the function hook_views_query_alter is also not possible.                                                           Please tell any alternative way to solve this problem